# Add to cart is not working: Uncaught TypeError

Tags: product, cart, error, magento-2.0, jquery

Add to cart is not working and getting error:

> section-config.js:33 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '*' of
>   undefined

I am very new to magento and by following docs, I have created a custom theme overriding the default LUMA theme.

And when i try to add a product to cart it shows Adding.. and loader keeps spinning.

I get following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '*' of undefined
at Object.getAffectedSections (section-config.js:33)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (customer-data.js:218)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.js:5226)
at HTMLDocument.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4878)
at Object.trigger (jquery.js:5130)
at Object.jQuery.event.trigger (jquery-migrate.js:493)
at done (jquery.js:9858)
at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery.js:10311)
```

I tried flushing cache, deleting everything inside var folder and also changed url from http://localhost/dir-name to http://127.0.0.1/dir-name but no luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be something with update section of mini cart has problem.
If you are logged in as customer , it may also update some customer realted details.
Check for custom modules related to cart and customer.

Comment: @gaurang I have not created any custom modules related to cart or customer!. anyways i will login as a customer and give a try.

Comment: @user1296187 , Can please check weather you forget to include some js file in theme or something. It looks like some object can not readble by js.

Comment: @GaurangPadhiyar thank you for your help, it was the below code in default.xml causing the problem <referenceContainer name="main">
            <container name="content.top" label="Main Content Top"/>
            <container name="content" label="Main Content Area"/>
            <container name="content.aside" label="Main Content Aside"/>
            <container name="content.bottom" label="Main Content Bottom"/>
 </referenceContainer>